# How to modify/update content of tabular parameter in JBehave example table

Tags: jbehave

I need to modify content value of Example table of Scenario of JBehave story file through a Step-file (Java-method) will it be possible ?

e.g.**Story file**

```
Scenario :Modifying_Example_Table

Given Previous values of example_table_row <Product_Sold>

Given Change the status of Product_Sold by Java method    

Given Print both previous and current status of Product_Sold

Examples:

|Product_Sold |

|"No"|
```

**So can we update the value of Column Product_Sold by the step**

"Given Change the status of Product_Sold by Java method" 
as below

```
|Product_Sold |

|"Yes"|
```

!--value of Product_Sold changed from **"No" to "Yes"** that I want by some code inside Step file

**Step File** :

```
@Given(Change the status of Product_Sold by Java method )
public void SomeJavaMethod()
{
//Some ExampleTable code to modify the value of  tabular parameter "Product_Sold"    

}
```

so what should be the code  inside above method in step file ?

Answer (score 1):

To manipulate the "Product_Sold" value, you need to put both values in the Examples Table as shown below:

```
Examples:
|<Product_Sold>|
|"No"|
|"Yes"|
```

**Step File:**

```java
@Given(Change the status of Product_Sold by Java method )
public void changeStatusOfProductSold(ExamplesTable table)
{
   boolean replaceNamedParameters = true;
   // Select the value "Yes" for Product_Sold
   table.getRowAsParameters(1, replaceNamedParameters).valueAs("Product_Sold", String.class);

}
```

To have a better understanding of how to manipulate tabular parameters in jbehave example tabe, follow the below mentioned link
http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/tabular-parameters.html